# Automatic meeting declination

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to automatically check incoming meeting-requests:

- If the request is from someone external nothing should happen
- If the request is from someone of my company (checking the E-Mail Max.Mustermann@mycompany.com) it should check whether I already have an accepted meeting in the asked timeframe and decline the request by default (plus answering).

I know basic Excel VBA but not familiar with Outlook. I tried to trigger the code with every incoming mail checking if it's a meeting request but don't get how to import the message and it's message type. I found some snippets while researching but it will throw an error.

This is where I am:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

'Dim oResponse
'    Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
'    oResponse.Display

MsgBox ("Testing")

End Sub
```

The event won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

```
Private Sub outApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mai As Object
    Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)
    MsgBox mai.Subject


End Sub
```

Then you can check the message class and cast the object to the right type. Or just check the type name:

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MeetingItem" Then
```

Later you may check the sender related properties, for example, the `SenderEmailAddress` property returns a string that represents the email address of the sender of the Outlook item.